# How to dissuade laypeople from drawing inaccurate conclusions about their data?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, assumptions, accuracy

I work as a data analyst, primarily in SQL, providing operations data to internal customers.  I rarely do statistical analysis.

Recently, internal customers have been coming to me with data from badly designed projects (no control group, no planned methodology, etc) and asking me to do data analysis on their results so they can use it to shape their business practices.

The "studies" are very rudimentary, executed by people with no knowledge of research methods or statistics, and trying to influence important business practices.  I can't do statistical analysis on it because it was not designed right from the get-go.

What resources could I point them at to let them know their "studies" can't be generalized beyond the population involved? What language do I use for this?

Comment: "To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of." —Ronald Fisher

Answer (score 3):

I wish you had provided more details in your question, but I'm just going to answer it with whatever information you have provided.

I think it's unlikely that they will go back and actually peruse the "resources" you suggest, so you might be better off with reading about these yourself and trying to explain it them with examples. You can brief them about how they could have designed the experiment in the first place, maybe with an example of A/B testing (check it out on wikipedia), and how it is imperative that the sample is representative of the population. 
Links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments

Also, listing some possible pitfalls of drawing conclusions from statistically unsound experiments should help them understand your point. 
Link: http://www.ch.embnet.org/CoursEMBnet/Arrays06/files/arrays06_ExpDes2.pdf